# Why did Midna break the mirror of twilight?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

At the end of Twilight Princess, Midna broke the mirror of twilight [while saying](http://zeldawiki.org/Midna#Link) "Link... I... See you later".

As only the true ruler of twilight can break the mirror, Midna is clearly one. But why would she break the mirror as it's the only portal that connects the two worlds?

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty clear that Midna destroys the Mirror of Twilight to separate the Twilight Realm from Hyrule, since [she says](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess#Midna), *"... Light and shadow can't mix, as we all know. But... Never forget that there's another world bound to this one."* Referring to the events that gave progressed thus far in the game.

[The dialogue](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess#Dialogue) of before she breaks the mirror goes: *"Thank you... Well, the princess [referring to Zelda] spoke truly — as long as that mirror's around, we could meet again..."* After this she tearfully says *"Link... I... See you later..."* and then shatters the Mirror of Twilight with one of her tears.

Since she explicitly says **that mirror** and not **a mirror** it would imply that this is the only mirror connecting the two worlds.

Comment: Hmm I'm not so sure that there are more mirror connecting the two worlds. During the game Link specifically fix that mirror because Midna told him that it's the only way to Twilight.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely to spare the world of light from potentially being attacked and taken over again at some point in the future.